# PHP memory limit - OutOfMemoryException

Tags: php

I get this error message:

`Error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 13343871 bytes)`

I'm not surprised, because it's on a script which is generating a report with thousands of records (obtained with thousands of SQL queries - by it's nature it's just not ever going to be an efficient script). It's a slow script, which is okay - I've got a warning on the page to notify the user of this.

I just don't want this error happening.

The CSV file that gets generated appears to me to be complete (in terms of data), but at the bottom of the CSV file I get a stack trace and the OutOfMemoryException exception as in the message above.

For this particular part of the script I have overridden the PHP defaults:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Is there anything else I could be doing?

Comment: I'd try streaming the csv. Flush the output buffer every so often. Why keep the whole thing in memory before sending it?

Comment: if you dont care allocate even more memory

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from your question that you have assigned 512 MB RAM to PHP but as you are getting exception, your script needs more than that. If you have more RAM capabilities on your PC, just increase this RAM allocation to higher value.

However, keeping everything in memory is not a good idea. You should write it to disk in chunks & release used memory to minimize usage.

Comment: The virtual server I'm using, from memory, has a maximum of 512MB RAM but another 512MB of virtual memory. If I increase the memory limit to 1GB, will the PHP script start using virtual memory too? Or does the PHP memory limit refer to physical memory only?

Comment: @b85411 It's likely that it's using some virtual memory (or swap) already - the OS will need some disk space too. Swap is really slow though, so it's normally better to optimise the algorithm / code to use less memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest increasing the memory of the machine. Exhausting memory is really never a good idea, and will stop your script from executing like it should, if not at all - depending on the circumstances.

In terms of suppressing the error - IE. the stack-trace - you're receiving, be sure you've turned off error reporting with

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
error_reporting(0);
```

This will only work if the memory exhaustion isn't totally stopping the execution, though.